# PHP Solution to Generate Radar Chart

Tags: php, pdf, graph, survey, radar-chart

A client of mine currently uses a **ASP.net** application that allows him to conduct a user survey based on 30 Questions and generate an Excel Report. 
The process is time consuming and labor intensive as it consists of 5-6 steps..

He wants a **PHP solution** that can **generate report** and can be sent in **PDF format**..

The trciky part is the **Pentagon Charts/Radar Charts**..

Excel I guess has set of functions to generate these charts but **how do I do this using PHP?**

Check the URL below..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpyiq.png

Quick Help Highly Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pankaj,

Here are few examples of OpenSource PHP Radar/Polar Charts

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple8 - **Highly Recommended**

http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/docs/plottype/tutorial_plottype.radarchart.pkg.html

http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch16s02.html

Comment: Just is someone else reads this... pChart does not seem to work anymore.